# Form post not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have coded the following and its posting the data as I can see it in console. However, it does not seem to add to the database. I think it could be my condition in the process.php file for action: add_new, but I'm not sure.

Not a huge person on PHP so unsure how to see why it's failing but it's returning successfully to the AJAX, I think but not adding to database, so I assume it might be what I said above.

```
if($_POST['action'] == "add_new"){
```

jQuery and Form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.success').hide();    
        $("form#add_new").submit(function() {
            var started = "<?php echo time(); ?>";
        var duration = $('#duration').val();
        var ticket_price = $('#ticket_price').val();
        var win_percentage = $('#win_percentage').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var available = $('#available').val();
        var action = "add_new";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/process.php",
            data: { started: started, duration: duration, ticket_price: ticket_price, win_percentage: win_percentage, description: description, available: available, action: action },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                    $('form#add_new').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
            }
        });
        return false;
        });
    });
```

```
<div class="success">successfully added new ticket</div>
    <form id="add_new" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                  <label for="duration" class="control-label">Duration (days)</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="duration" class="input-xlarge" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label for="ticket_price" class="control-label">Ticket Price</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="ticket_price" name="ticket_price" class="input-xlarge" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label for="available" class="control-label">Available to be Won(%)</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="available" name="available" class="input-xlarge" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label for="win_percentage" class="control-label">Percentage of Winners</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="win_percentage" name="win_percentage" class="input-xlarge" value="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label for="description" class="control-label">Description</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <textarea rows="4" id="description" name="description" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
                    <span class="help-block">Automatic resize</span> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">
                    <button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
```

`process.php`:

```
<?php

include "../utils.php"; 

// Add new raffle ticket
if($_POST['action'] == "add_new"){
    $started = $_POST['started'];
    $duration = $_POST['duration']; 
    $ticket_price = $_POST['ticket_price'];
    $win_percentage = $_POST['win_percentage'];
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $available = $_POST['available'];

    my_query("INSERT INTO " . $db_prefix . " (lotteries(started, duration, ticket_price, win_percentage, description,available) values) VALUES ('$started','$duration','$ticket_price','$win_percentage','$description','$available')");
    mysql_query($add_to_shelf) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe one of the values entered doesn't match the field, or you have more fields in the table. To troubleshoot it in a better way try to use the php file alone and use some values "hardcode" it in there! If it passes that, then it's the jquery not parsing it, specially at one specific field.

Comment: Could you copy paste the posted data here? I suspect that there is no `action` variable.

Comment: started=1371329003&duration=31&ticket_price=1&win_percentage=0.1&description=testing&available=80&action=add_new is what is in the post data in firebug

Comment: Ok I read further, you are adding it from your AJAX call, there was no `action` in the form that's why I wondered. Do you get an answer from the server? What is the response code?

Comment: I'm sure this is NOT what is causing your problem, but I noticed that you didn't include a name attribute for the duration input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In God I trust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1624960/in-god-i-trust) is right. Using PDO is much safer. Here's a short example on how to insert into your database:

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare("INSERT INTO customer (name, email, password)
            VALUES (:name, :mail, :pass)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['full_name']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $_POST['email']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['password']);

            $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I went long the PDO approach last night and got it working, i have an issue with passing the success and error response back but that is something else. Thanks for your advise Nilzone-!

Answer (score 0):

There is too much wrong but for a start there is no function called `my_query`. On your second last line in the PHP. If I were you I would check the PHP code works properly first using basic GET variables or something, and then work on the POST variables.

When you finished that, your code is subject to **mysql injection**. You need to take a look at stopping these deprecated `mysql_` functions and move to a supported type like `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I would suggest

1) to check whether or not your PHP is called
2) to check what it is doing and what are the results.

If you don't have the tool box to do so, here are some useful functions:

```
function PrintLog($string)
{
    if (! BDEBUG)
        return ;

    $logDir = LOGPATH;
    if (! file_exists($logDir))
    {
        umask(000);
        if (! mkdir($logDir, 0777))
            ErrorLog("Failed to create Directory $logDir");
        chmod($logDir, 0777);
    }

    $fplog = @fopen($logDir.'/'.'debug-'.date('Y-m-d').'.log', 'a');
    if ($fplog)
    {
        fwrite($fplog, date("d-m-Y  H:i:s")."\t".$string);
        fwrite($fplog, "\n");
        fclose($fplog);
    }
}
function PrintrLog(&$arrayToDump, $strName = '')
{
    ob_start();
    print_r($arrayToDump);
    PrintLog("$strName = ".ob_get_contents());
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Insert in your PHP script those function and the code:

```
define("BDEBUG", true);
define("LOGPATH", "./log/");
PrintrLog( $_POST);
```

Then, have a look to the log file generated.
If nothing, look at your Apache logs, may be some error will be here waiting for you to fix.
If log is here, check if the POST is how it should be, then it's probably a problem in your SQL. 
I don't know much about your DB schema, but intuitively, I would write something more like that :

```
$my_query = "INSERT INTO lotteries (started, duration, ticket_price, win_percentage, description,available) VALUES ('$started', '$duration', '$ticket_price', '$win_percentage', '$description', '$available')"; 
PrintLog($my_query); // Take it from logs, and run it manually inPHPmyAdmin to debug it eaily
```

You can add this this kind of function too in your toolbox:

```
function ExecQuery($Cnx, $baseName, $query, &$sqlError)
{
    PrintLog($query);
    $result = mysql_query($query, $Cnx);
    if (! $result)
    {
        $sqlError = "ERROR: Failed to execute query '$query' [".mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error().']';
        PrintLog($sqlError); 
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I hope this will help you in your current and future investiguations ;-)

PS: You should also think about using such a function to systematicaly avoid SQL injection:

```
function getPostValue($name) {
    if (! isset($_POST[$name]))
        return '';
    return(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$name]));
}
```